# UISwitch changing object parse objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-server

I am working on a app that you can change when a item on the menu is in stock or out of stock. [image]

I have it now so it changes the `UISwitch` to on or off when it loads the screen. I need each switch to change a `NSString` in `parse` that makes it one or zero.One meaning that it is on zero meaning its off.

[image]

I am fairly new to `objective c` and `parse` so if any one could help me get a start on this problem that would be great!

Comment: Parse is really well documented.  Have you looked at any of that?

Comment: @Dancreek I know how to add and remove objects I do not know how I should change a object with a switch on a table view application because each cell has the same button with the same tag

Comment: How are you populating your UITableViewCell's with the data from Parse?  As @Dancreek indicated, Parse has many tutorials online that show how to populate almost any kind of iOS control.  Have you gone thru any of those?

Comment: FYI - Parse is going away. You should not be using for any new projects.

Comment: @rmaddy I am running open source parse on AWS

Answer (score 1):

You might use something like that:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"YourClass"];
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject * yourClass, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
    // Found yourClass object
    [yourClass setObject:isInStock forKey:@"isInStock"];

    // Save
    [yourClass saveInBackground];
  } else {
    // Did not find any yourClass object for the current user
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
  }
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *listObjects = .... (loading from Server) // List of PFObject

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

PFObject *object = [listObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

YourCell *cell = .....

if ([[object valueForKey:@"sandwichesOutofstock"] intValue] == 1)
   cell.switch.on = true;
else
  cell.switch.on = false;
cell.switch.tag = 500 + index.row;
[cell.switch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchTouch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
.........



}

(IBAction)switchTouch:(UISwitch *)switch{
    long index = switch.tag - 500;
    PFObject *object = [listObjects objectAtIndex:index];
    if(switch.on)
        [object setValue:@"1" ForKey:@"sandwichesOutofstock"];
    else{
        [object setValue:@"0" ForKey:@"sandwichesOutofstock"];
    }
    [object saveInBackground];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could assign a reference of the PFObject to the cell. Then when the switch changes just get the cell's object and make the change.